# af:inputDate :: getting ADFFacesMessage error

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I am using ADF Faces components in my WebLayer.While using the dateComponent

I am getting some faces message error.Pls find my jsf code

```
<af:inputDate label="Date" value="#{innerRow.dateValue}"
              maxValue="#{innerRow.maxValue}"
              minValue="#{innerRow.minValue}"  
              valueChangeListener="#{pageFlowScope.myBean.valuechangeMethod}"
              converter="javax.faces.DateTime">
    <af:convertDateTime pattern="#{innerRow.datePattern}"/>
</af:inputDate>
```

In valuechange method following code is written

```
valueChangeEvent.getComponent().processUpdates(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
```

Other attributes are from my ManagedBean class

```
public class MyBean{
  private Date dateValue;
  private Date maxValue;
  private Date minValue;
  private String datePattern;
  // getter & setter
}
```

Whenever I am trying to pick any date from the calendar I am moving into exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.SimpleInputDateRenderer._setupChooseDate(SimpleInputDateRenderer.java:1561)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.SimpleInputDateRenderer._setupPopupChooser(SimpleInputDateRenderer.java:1675)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.SimpleInputDateRenderer.decodeInternal(SimpleInputDateRenderer.java:99)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.LabeledInputRenderer.decodeInternal(LabeledInputRenderer.java:74)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.decode(RichRenderer.java:399)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.decode(CoreRenderer.java:305)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.__rendererDecode(UIXComponentBase.java:1750)
```

Can anyone has any solution to this????

Comment: is the myBean added properly on the task flow as having pageFlowScope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the pageFlowScope at the valueChangeListener